# Apt stucked in setting up libc6

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glibc, wsl-2, apt

When I installed Debian WSL2 in my new computer,I just know some wrong "common sence" from other Debian distros. So I thougnt, someone said Debian Stable is too old, so they use Debian tesing for newer software. And Ubuntu is based on Debian sid, can I just use the sid source of Debian? So I choosen Debian sid for my WSL source. (When this problem happend, I looked up the neofetch. Neo etch still show it Debian 11)It works great at first time, but yesterday, when I try to upgrade WSL just like before, it takes a long while and didn't finish. I saw apt stucked in setting up libc6(2.37-13), I don't know what apt was doing.

I tried a stupid solution: reboot WSL. It doesn't work. I looked up logs of dpkg, and I saw this:

## 2024-01-07 22:15:52 status half-configured libc6:amd64 2.37-13

And I tried to use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490671/fix-half-installed-package) site talk about:

## sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename

It doesn't work for me. Apt output these:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-bin libc-l10n locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc-l10n locales
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5216 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libc6:amd64
```

I don't find any solution about this error.

Comment: Mine is stuck at: `Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.37-13) ...` for two hours. No time to debug now, I will leave it overnight, but doubt it will help. Also WSL, Debian unstable. Will report back if I find out anything...

Comment: Nothing happened over night, still stuck at the same spot. I guess some debugging will need to take place.

Comment: Which Debian version (such as : stable,testing,sid) do you use in your WSL? If this problem is not becasue we did some wrong operation, maybe we should report this as a bug on the Bug Tracking System (BTS)  of debian.

Comment: That's what I was planning to do but haven't had time yet. I'm on trixie/sid (and WSL 2 like the rest of you, with the same behavior with this package).

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=libc6-amd64

Comment: I was on WSL2, sid. Unfortunately I had to work, so I went with the path of the least resistancem, nuked the VM and created a new one on stable :) I will keep an eye on this topic, to see when can I switch to sid again.

Comment: I just submitted the bug report. I'll post a link when available.

Comment: Debian bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1060387

Comment: setting this in /etc/wsl.conf
`[boot]
systemd=true
`
fixed this issue
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10955#issuecomment-1894003593

Comment: Sadly,it doesn't work for me

Comment: I fixed this with `sudo mv /usr/sbin/telinit /usr/sbin/telinit.bak` and then `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/true /usr/sbin/telinit`.

Comment: @mtraceur, you should post your comment as an answer because it works.

Comment: @PedroLobito thanks! But a comment was all I could do, because we can't post new answers to closed questions

Comment: Found another workaround: run apt upgrade and when it gets stuck on configuring libc6 kill telinit from another session (in my case ps was showing telinit using 99.6% CPU).